# How can I count occurrences of words specified in an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, user-input

I am working on a small program in which the user enters text and I would like to check how many times the given words occur in the given input.

```
# Read user input
print("Input your code: \n")

user_input = sys.stdin.read()
print(user_input)
```

For example, the text that I input in a program is:

```
a=1
b=3
if (a == 1):
    print("A is a number 1")
elif(b == 3):
    print ("B is 3")
else: 
    print("A isn't 1 and B isn't 3")
```

The words to find out are specified in an array.

```
wordsToFind = ["if", "elif", "else", "for", "while"]
```

And basically I would like to print how many "if", "elif" and "else" has occurred in a input.

How can I count occurrences of words like "if", "elif", "else", "for", "while" in a given string by user input?

Comment: Turn the strings into regular expressions with word boundaries. Then you can find all the matches, and use `collections.Counter()` to count them.

Comment: You need the word boundaries so that `if` won't match `elif`.

Comment: So the regexp should be `\b(if|elif|else|for|while)\b`

Comment: @Barmar I wrote several 'if's and I used findall() method and wanted to print that length, but it says 0
`print(len(re.findall(regexp, user_input)))`

Comment: Sounds like your regexp isn't correct. Don't forget to use a raw string so that `\b` will be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best option is to use the `tokenize` built-in module of python:

```py
# Let's say this is tokens.py
import sys
from collections import Counter
from io import BytesIO
from tokenize import tokenize

# Get input from stdin
code_text = sys.stdin.read()

# Tokenize the input as python code
tokens = tokenize(BytesIO(code_text.encode("utf-8")).readline)

# Filter the ones in wordsToFind
wordsToFind = ["if", "elif", "else", "for", "while"]
words = [token.string for token in tokens if token.string in wordsToFind]

# Count the occurrences
counter = Counter(words)

print(counter)
```

### Test

Let's say you have a `test.py`:

```
a=1
b=3
if (a == 1):
    print("A is a number 1")
elif(b == 3):
    print ("B is 3")
else: 
    print("A isn't 1 and B isn't 3")
```

and then you run:

```
cat test.py | python tokens.py
```

Output:

```
Counter({'if': 1, 'elif': 1, 'else': 1})
```

### Advantages

- Only correct python (syntactically) will be parsed
- You only will be counting the python keywords (not every *if* occurrence in the code text, for example, you can have an line like

  `a = "if inside str"`

  That *if* should not be counted I think